Scraping excel data from PowerPoint slides
I have PowerPoint slides sent to me with data I need to populate my Power BI dashboard. I have been obtaining the data by opening each slide, double-clicking the table image, and then doing a copy-paste into an Excel workbook.  I have tried saving the slides as zip files and trying to grab the Excel file from that.  Unfortunately, the system I get the slides from treats the tables as just images and does not create the Excel file I need.  The big issue is having 600+ slides to collect data from and it becomes very time-consuming.  Is there any way I can extract the data from those slides without having to spend my whole morning copy-pasting. Is there a way I can scrape the data using Python?

I think google is your friend on this one or try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQuT9edc3cA&t=740s or
https://medium.com/@alice.yang_10652/create-or-extract-tables-in-powerpoint-presentations-with-python-4dae200fa9d0
